# how to pass uri response to another function and get length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, ember.js

I tried to pass uri response to another function and to get length of that passed response. I got success in first step. but while getting length it gives wrong lengths. How to overcome that? please help me.

I tried this code.

```
importfn : function() {
  new URI(Org, self.get('currentOrg.ORG_ID'), GIHNBV)
          .POST(hghgb)
          .then(function(res) {
              self.send("addfromua", res);
           }
}
addfromua : function(res) {
   for(var rl=0; rl <arguments.length; rl++){
       console.log(res[rl);
   }
}
```

I got JsonArray as response in the uri call and passed it to the "addfromua" function successfully. but while trying to get that jsonarra length as "arguments.length" it gives me always 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not `arguments` it should be `res`

```
addfromua : function(res) {
   for(var rl=0; rl <res.length; rl++){
       console.log(res[rl);
   }
}
```

Comment: No i tried this. it returns undefined. If i print "res" in console it return an object with my response. but while trying res.length it return undefined.

Comment: res is array or object?

Comment: object. I found result. i tried res.attributes.length it gives me the length of the object successfullt.

Comment: Thanks for your response